# data-hint in ng-grid cell header

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-grid

I am trying to use data-hint on mousing over a question mark glyphicon from Twitter Bootstrap 3.2 with the cell header template of ngGrid. However, mousing over the icon brings up a box that is covered by the borders of the header cell. How would I go about making the entire hint show up?